# Proving that something is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that the set of all functions g of the form g : x′= (x + a) and
>   y′ = (y + b) is a group under the composition of functions, for a, b ∈
>   R.

I know that to prove something is a group, you need to examine it for the following four criteria: closure, associativity, identity and inverse. But I don't know where I can go about solving this problem as I don't entire understand what I am being asked or how to go about it.

Comment: To be clear: Does that notation mean that the functions under consideration are from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and on the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y+b)$ for some pair of reals $(a,b)$?

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine so.

Comment: @RoySheehan You "would imagine"? Where is the question from that you cannot be positive about what's being asked?

Comment: @DonAntonio It is from a tutorial sheet that I was given in college. Literally everything that I know about the question is on the post. I'm not great at maths, so apologies if I sounded stupid. The course that I am on is an introduction to mathematical study so I don't know if we are going into too much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define for any pair of real numbers $\;a,b\;$

$$f_{a,b}(x,y):=(x+a,y+b)\implies $$

$$f_{a,b}\circ f_{c,d}(x,y)=f_{a,b}(x+c,y+d)=((x+c)+a,(y+d)+b)=f_{a+c,b+d}(x,y)$$

and we have closedness

Now check that

$$f_{a,b}\circ f_{-a,-b}(x,y)=(x,y)=Id.(x,y)$$

I leave to you associativity.